# What is the meaning of this two letter code in the YouTube logo?

Tags: youtube

I see a new logo with `CA` at `youtube.com`. Does anyone know what it means?

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That is due to you accessing the Canadian locale of the site.

If you go to `http://www.youtube.ca` you'll be redirected to `http://www.youtube.com/?gl=CA` with the CA in the logo.

If you accidentally got to that version you can just visit `http://www.youtube.com/?gl=US` and it will give you the US version.

The two letters signify the two-character country code for countries. A complete listing can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2#Decoding_table)

Comment: I must have accidentally visited an Canadian link to Youtube, which caused my `Country` setting to change. I'm not from Canada. I just overlooked Country at the bottom of page. :) Thanks for clarifying. I was thinking that Youtube just started to propagate home state California.. :)

Comment: Very strange, I have the same thing.  Comes up as Youtube CA for me as well.  I'm very much in the USA, with a US ISP, etc.  I'll have to try the fix...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's a locale identifier. I'm in the US at the moment but usually live in Belgium. If I am logged into my Google account and visit YouTube.com I see "BE", but if I'm using an anonymous profile I see the US version.

When I am logged in, adding a new locale in the query string has no effect, I remain on the BE branded site.